# JNI:converting jstring(full of number) into jint using Integer.pasteInt by jvmti caused Crash

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

```
    jclass in = jniEnv->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
    jmethodID ipi = jniEnv->GetStaticMethodID(in, "parseInt", "(Ljava/lang/String;)I");

    jint test = jniEnv->CallStaticIntMethod(in, ipi,  (jstring)jniEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(System, getProperty, jniEnv->NewStringUTF("input")));
```

Here is my code
I try to conver a jstring("10029909473242") into a jint
But if i try to print it it crash the vm.
is there a better solution?
Thanks.

```
    jclass JOptionPane = jniEnv->FindClass("javax/swing/JOptionPane");
    jmethodID showInputDialog = jniEnv->GetStaticMethodID(JOptionPane, "showInputDialog", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;");
    jniEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(NULL, showInputDialog, test);
```

Comment: （*(jstring)jniEnv-> CallStaticObjectMethod(System, getProperty,
 jniEnv->NewStringUTF("input"))*  return ->"10029909473242"）

Comment: Why are you passing `NULL` as the `clazz` argument to `CallStaticObjectMethod`? Shouldn't that be `JOptionPane`?

Comment: i tested it.It works with the code:[link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qGNWvnj4th/).@Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show an actual error, but I can guess at one reason:
10029909473242 is too large to fit into a Java `int` so I bet `Integer.parseInt` threw a `NumberFormatException`. Calling any JNI method with a pending exception will crash the JVM.

The root cause here is that you should use `Long.parseLong` instead, but you should additionally add error checking by calling `ExceptionOccurred` or `ExceptionCheck` after each `Call*Method` call. Then either return to the JVM or call `ExceptionClear` and continue in native code.

Comment: thanks.Is there any method to save the error message into a String var just like Java.

Comment: ExceptionOccurred returns the exception object. (or null)

Answer (score 0):

```
char buf1[64];

sprintf(buf1, "%d", p);
```

solved

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your answer: [code only answers can be low-quality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)

Comment: @MZ emm This might be a C++ problem.I think sprintf is to put int into a buf